# Where can one find a full list of SharePoint URL Query options?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, url, query

If I am asking a duplicate for this, please let me know and I'll gladly peruse that question.

I'm looking for a full list of all the different options available for SharePoint queries (note - not using `search/query?querytext. . .` )

Example: `sharepointsite/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx?q=searchtexthere&env=WebViewList`

I understand `q=` is what I'm looking to query the list for, but I'm having trouble finding a full list of what options `env=` supports.  I've only seen `WebView`, `WebViewList`, and `Embedded` - is this all?  What I'm wanting to do is provide a `text-only` result with absolutely no links or formatting.  Is this possible?

Is there a fully defined list all the supported query options?  I have a terrible time navigating the MSDN site, so if it is there in plain text, then please point me, and forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I also found this 3 values only in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/query-string-url-tricks-sharepoint-m365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get the "text-only" list view without links or formatting using `env` query string parameter if you have used hyperlinks columns or JSON formatting in SharePoint list.

You will require a custom solution to show the "text-only" list view by removing formatting/links from all columns.

I also found below 3 values only for `env` parameter in documentation:

1. `Embedded`: Create a focused view of just content similar to classic experience `isDLg=1` or using [Focus mode from SharePoint UI](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/21/introducing-focus-mode-for-modern-sharepoint-pages/)
2. `WebView`: Focus mode with hidden hub site navigation
3. `WebViewList`: Show any SharePoint List as a *Microsoft Lists* List

Comment: Thanks!  This is all I was finding too - guess it's not just me this time!